Podman logging all interactive output?
Docker aware user seeking for alternatives tries podman (e.g. 4.3.1 on Debian 12),
then e.g. podman run -it alpine:latest, then e.g. installs and runs mc,
and in the syslog (e.g. journalctl -af in the bottom vertical-split tmux window pane) to own great surprise sees session outputs (incl. terminal graphics apps')!
Is it really correct default behavior?
(There is neither /etc/podman* nor /etc/default/podman*, and the manual page says default --log-level is warn and --syslog is false.)
If it is, is it e.g. because of some specific usage of podman vs docker?
And mainly, how is podman configured to log at most external container actions (and why it by default logs all) ?



Related discussion: RFE: Use --log-driver none when not running --detached

Podman has effectively the same logging behavior as Docker: they both log all output produced by a container.
Podman logs to the journal by default, while Docker logs to a JSON-line format log file. They're both logging exactly the same data. If you configured Docker to use the journald log driver, you would see the same behavior as you see with Podman.
Just like with Docker, you can configure Podman to use a different log driver; see e.g. the podman run documentation. Podman includes a json-file driver, which is what Docker uses by default.
